# Error using && operator

Tags: java

```
public boolean isRight() {
    if(xposition == ( (oposition-1) && (oposition != (12 && 8 && 4))) {
        return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

"xposition" and "oposition" are assigned values during the runtime of a program.

The error is in `(12 && 8 && 4)`  I need to make sure that the value of "oposition" is not equal to 12 and 8 and 4.

I don't know what is wrong here. Please help

Comment: Is it java or c++?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Please make you if statement readable instead of using this 'junk'. Divide it up.

Comment: Can you say in English what you want the expression to do? Its not even close to compiling at the moment.

Comment: @Kos : your much appreciated question is rhetorical.  "The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int".  Error message on the '12 && 8' part in my Eclipse/java installation.  So it's not java.  Curiously, in those few seconds I needed to look this up, it's his C++ tag that got removed ??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe right logic is:

```
if(xposition == ( (oposition-1) && (oposition != 12 && oposition != 8 && oposition != 4) ) )
```

If you have a lot of numbers:

```
int[] numbers = { 
    12, 8, 4, 13, 2, 7
};
boolean validation = true;
for (int i : numbers) {
    if (oposition == i) {
        validation = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Does it matter if it gets lengthy? i have around twelve number that should not be equal to oposition. Do i write them as oposition!= 12 different times?

Comment: In this case better way is to use loop in array with list of your numbers.

Answer (score 6):

> I don't know what is wrong here.

The logic. What would you expect `(12 && 8 && 4)` to evaluate to? (Hint: it's `true`)

Do you think `oposition != (12 && 8 && 4)` means that `opposition` is different than those values?

Comment: @veredesmarald you get +1 internets.

Comment: In C++ defitely, but does Java even allow `true && 4`? I can't remember

Comment: @Kos, in Java it is a compile time error: `The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) int, int`.

Comment: Small nitpick, oposition (the position of O) != opposition (your opponents), and "it's true" is not really a _hint_ :-)

Comment: @veredesmarald : and from me, you get +1 stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know your error message, probably the issue is that you're comparing `xposition` (which looks like a number) with the result of `operator&&` inside the parentheses.

Also later you're trying to compare `oposition` with the result of `(12 && 8 && 4)` which doesn't look useful, even if a language would permit it.

Pay attention to the parentheses.

Probably you meant something like:

```
if (xposition == opposition-1
    && opposition != 12
    && opposition != 8
    && opposition != 4)
{
    // ...  
}
```

Indentation helps when there's a lot of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're comparing a boolean statement to a (potential) int value.  What I think you need is:

```
if((xposition == oposition-1) &&
        (oposition != 12 && oposition != 8 && oposition != 4)))
```

The statement 12 && 8 && 4 makes no sense.  You *have* to compare each individual number against your variable.